# Unable to change mysql db format from STATEMENT to ROW

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'am using `mysql 5.5.21` and trying to change mysql db from STATEMENT format to ROW for replication purpose.

I tried it in two ways 
editing the configuration file or during the runtime.

1.The changes I have done in configuration file is adding a line under `mysqld "--binlog-format=ROW` to change it into row format but it didn't work.

2.Again I tried to change it during run time, for that I declared the command

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
```

Also I logedin as super user in mysql.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.